# Android Display PNG File

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am using a code example from the web to capture a Signature.
This code appears to work fine and it saves the signature image as a PNG file in my Application Files directory (where I want it to be).
The code for that is:

```
        public void save(View v)
    {
        FileDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();  // "/data/data/<myapp>/files/"
        current = "capturedsignature.png";

        mypath = new File(FileDir, current);

        if(mBitmap == null)
        {
            mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            //FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(mypath.toString(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            //String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Again, that part seems to work just fine.
I even confirm that the file is saved by examining:  mypath.exists() and it is TRUE

Now I want to use that signature in another manner.
But before I attempt to use it I want to ensure that it was saved OK.
In order to do that I have temporarily added an Image Confirm layout where I want to display the signature.
But I cannot get it to work - and since it is not working, I am guessing that my REAL intended usage will also not work.

So here is the code I am using to retrieve and display the PNG file.

```
        // Build Signature File Pathed Reference
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String FileDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();  // "/data/data/<myapp>/files/"

    String ImgFileName = WorkingStorage.GetCharVal(Defines.SignatureFile, getApplicationContext());
    String ImgFileStr = FileDir +  "/" + ImgFileName;
    File ImgFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath(), ImgFileName);

    //check if image exists
    FileInputStream in;
    BufferedInputStream buf;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(ImgFileStr);
        buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
        ImgView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
    }
```

While watching the code execute I examine if the file to be retrieved exists with:   ImgFile.exists()  and I get TRUE
Despite that the image that is being displayed is coming up all BLACK - not the signature image that I THOUGHT that I saved.

For reference purposes here is the layout XML code that is intended to display the ImgView
NOTE - in another app I use this layout where I save a JPG file to the directory:  /storage/emulated/0 and retrieve it for review purposes.  That works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Review Plate Image"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="36dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_review"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="285dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >
</ImageView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_review">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SaveBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NoSaveBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/SaveBtn"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you post the layout.xml file wich contains the ImgView?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   See the XML code below - as noted it is working just fine in another app.

Comment: did you tried my ans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try file stream instead,

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FileDir +  "/" + ImgFileName);
```

then

```
ImgView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

hope it works..

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  That code runs without an error, but the ImageView is also showing a totally BLACK image - not the signature from the file that I saved.

Comment: make sure you are getting a valid image, for that you just save it to external storage, and check whether it is clean or not.

Comment: Again, thank you for your reply.  OK, I set a Debug 2nd File save to where I could actually look at the image with the Photo Gallery.   Since the file save was Good, I was assuming that the captured image was Good ---  Bad Assumption.    Now I have to find out why the Saved Image is not good.

Comment: It turns out that some minor code modifications was messing things up.  Once I reverted to the original code, the image started saving as needed.  Thank you for your input, it put me onto the right track to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have to find out why the Saved Image is not good

The image is black probably because drawing on canvas is not saved as bitmap properly. You will solve it with little effort but allow me to suggest you another solution for this problem.

There is a libaray called [SignatureView](https://github.com/zahid-ali-shah/SignatureView) on github (see link below), you can use this library without any hassle.

It will return you signature as Bitmap, you can save it as (PNG) picture or use it in any other view. Code is tested and verified and it works. You can also download demo app from [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kyanogen.signature).

Github repository also contains an example from where you can see how library is implemented.